# How to create MultiSelect dropDrown or Lookup in Enterprise Portal Dynamics Ax 2009?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, enterprise-portal

I want to create MultiSelect Dropdown or lookup on EP page in Dynamics AX 2009 ?
Any suggestion please I am new to EP.

Answer (score 1):

I dont' know if I can help you, 
on Web I found a Tutorial for Dynamics - Ax 2012. You can try this Way , if you want.

http://www.dynamics101.com/2014/11/using-multi-select-lookup-control-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012/

I hope I have understood the question.

Good work!